# Slow down tab select animation

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout

I am doing a Intro Activity that consists in a TabLayout with three fragments.

I have two buttons below my TabLayout - one for "Skip" the intro and the other for "Next" screen/tab. They are working fine but I would like to make some changes on the "Next" function:

When I click the "Next" button he does this:

```
tabLayout.getTabAt(tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition() + 1).select()
```

And he is indeed selecting the next tab, but I was wondering if I could slow down the slide/swap animation of the tab. Can I somewhat Override de animation so I can slow it down?

**EDIT**

I created a custom class that extends TabLayout:

```
public class CustomTabLayout extends TabLayout {

    public CustomTabLayout(Context context) { 
        super(context); 
    }

    public CustomTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { 
        super(context, attrs); 
    }

    public CustomTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) { 
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr); 
    }
}
```

And I noticed that the TabLayout class has this method:

```
 private void animateToTab(int newPosition) {
    if (newPosition == Tab.INVALID_POSITION) { return; }

    if (getWindowToken() == null || !ViewCompat.isLaidOut(this) || mTabStrip.childrenNeedLayout()) {
        setScrollPosition(newPosition, 0f, true);
        return;
    }

    final int startScrollX = getScrollX();
    final int targetScrollX = calculateScrollXForTab(newPosition, 0);

    if (startScrollX != targetScrollX) {
        ensureScrollAnimator();

        mScrollAnimator.setIntValues(startScrollX, targetScrollX);
        mScrollAnimator.start();
    }

    mTabStrip.animateIndicatorToPosition(newPosition, ANIMATION_DURATION);
}
```

The problem is that ANIMATION_DURATION is a private static final constant set to 300 in the TabLayout class. Can I somewhat change this value to 1000 for example to slow down the animation?

**EDIT 2**

As suggested by **azizbekian**, I am trying to change this value using reflection:

```
public CustomTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    setAnimationDuration();
}

static void setAnimationDuration() {
    try {
        Field field = TabLayout.class.getDeclaredField("ANIMATION_DURATION");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(field.get(TabLayout.class), 2000);

        int v = (int) field.get(TabLayout.class);
        //  v == 2000; so I guess that I changed the value successfully
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

But when my tabs are created, it still has the same transaction duration (to fast). Am I doing something wrong with reflection? Or this "ANIMATION_DURATION" is not the correct value to change?

Answer (score 0):

As you can [see in sources](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.java#L158), animation duration is not customizable:

```
private static final int ANIMATION_DURATION = 300;
...
mScrollAnimator.setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
```

So, it cannot be configured neither from styles (`xml`), nor through Java code.

Only thing you can try to do is to [change the value of **private static final** field through reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3301720/1083957).